# Read Large Json File in C#

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

I am trying to read a large Json (120Mb) File in C#.I am getting Memory Over flow exception. I am using the following code.

```
// Load the JObject directly from a file
using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(fileName))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    obj = JObject.Load(jsonReader);
}

// Rename all properties with primitive values (string, number, boolean, null) to begin with "@"
foreach (var o in obj.Descendants().OfType<JObject>())
{
  // Attributes must appear first in the JObject's property list.
int insertIndex = 0;
foreach (var property in o.Properties().Where((p => p.Value is JValue && !p.Name.StartsWith("@"))).ToList())
{
    property.Remove();
    ((IList<JToken>)o).Insert(insertIndex++, new JProperty("@" + property.Name, property.Value));
}
```

}

```
// Convert to XmlDocument
XmlDocument doc;
using (var reader = obj.CreateReader())
{
    doc = (XmlDocument)JsonExtensions.DeserializeXmlNode(reader);
}
```

Comment: Don't read it all at once as an object. You have a reader, read it in saving the parts you need...

Comment: How can I achieve tat?

Comment: 1) Are you using a 32 bit or 64 bit executable?  2) At what line does it throw the exception?

Comment: 64 bit. obj = JObject.Load(jsonReader); here I am getting error

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message and traceback and inner exception, if any?  What does the JSON file look like around the line at which the exception occurs?